# Killing Vectors of BTZ black hole and their calculation in general

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, symmetry, differential-geometry, vector-fields

I was wondering what are the Killing vectors of [BTZ black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTZ_black_hole) and how to guess them easily? Will it be the same as of AdS? What then will be Killing vectors for AdS-Schwarzschild e.g.?

Answer (score 1):

The geometry of the BTZ black hole, including its Killing vectors, is described in Steve Carlip's [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/grqc/9506079) (which I just noticed is also referenced by the wiki article).  Another good reference on this topic is [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9604005).

Basically, in the Schwarzschild-like coordinates, the Killing vectors are just $\partial_t$ and $\partial_{\phi}$.

As for how these Killing vectors can be "guessed" - the BTZ hole is obtained by quotienting AdS space by an isometry.  Since the isometry is itself generated by a Killing vector, I'd start by looking for Killing vectors on the original AdS which commute with the chosen isometry-generating one.

As for AdS-Schwarzschild, I'm not sure - it's only asymptotically AdS, so the AdS Killing vectors would only apply in some sort of limit.